# angular ngx-datatable ngFor row doesn't show data

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable and I want to use ngFor to show many data.
Now the table header has shown, but row cell data no display.
How to solve this problem?

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows">                                                   
    <ngx-datatable-column [name]="col.name" *ngFor="let col of columns">                                                        
        <ng-template let-value="value" let-expanded="expanded" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>                                                            
             {{ row.relevance }}                                                        
        </ng-template>                                                      
        <ng-template let-value="value" let-expanded="expanded" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>                                                           
             {{row.name}}                                                       
        </ng-template>                                                                                                               
        <ng-template let-value="value" let-expanded="expanded" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>                                                           
             {{row.price}}                                                      
        </ng-template>                                                                                                          
    </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>

columns = [
    { name: 'aaa' },
    { name: 'bbb' },
    { name: 'ccc' },
];
rows = [
    {   
        relevance: 'Austin', 
        name: 'Male', 
        price: 7
    },
    {   
        relevance: 'gfff', 
        name: 'des', 
        price: 4
    },
{   
        relevance: 'sosf', 
        name: 'qao', 
        price: 3
    }
];
```

Comment: where is row declared ?  {{row.price}} use  {{col.price}}

Comment: It still not work.

Comment: what is the error ? in console

Comment: there is no error, just no show data.

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295031/angular-ngx-datatable-multiple-data-in-one-column

Comment: here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable